# Typesafety with dlsym function loading

Tags: c++, c++0x

### Aim:

Use C++0x features to make function interposition safer. The problem is that it's easy to make a typo when wrapping and interposing on functions.

### Prototype Implementation:

```
#define MAKE_WRAPPER(x) static const wrapper<decltype(::x), ::x> x(#x)

namespace {
  template<typename Sig, Sig& S>
  struct wrapper;

  template<typename Ret, typename... Args, Ret(&P)(Args...)>
  struct wrapper<Ret(Args...), P> {
         typedef Ret(*real_func)(Args...);
         real_func f;
         wrapper(const std::string& sym) : f(NULL) {    
                dlerror();
                void *ptr = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, sym.c_str());
                f = (real_func)ptr;
                if (NULL == f) {
                  std::cerr << "dlsym(): " << dlerror() << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << "constructing wrapper: " << this << " for: " << sym << "(at " << ptr << ")" << std::endl;
         }

         Ret operator()(const Args&... args) const {
                return f(args...);
         }
  };
}
```

### Example usage:

```
extern "C" {
  void glXSwapBuffers(Display *dpy, GLXDrawable drawable) {
         MAKE_WRAPPER(glXSwapBuffers);
         // Do stuff here before making the call to the wrapper
         glXSwapBuffers(dpy, drawable);
  }
}
```

### Questions:

1. Is it worth the effort?
2. How can it be improved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ I'm assuming your example is meant to `return x(dpy, drawable);` rather than call itself recursively. ]

1. It's worth it if you have a use for it I guess.
2. Printing to `std::cerr` is not error handling, it's error logging. Pick a real error handling strategy and stick to it. Similarly is printing to `std::cout` necessary? I also believe that the fewer library calls there are in the constructor, the fewer risks of your wrapper calling itself recursively during static initialization of `x`, which will be disastrous.

Posix recommends the following way to cast when dealing with function types with `dlsym`:

```
*(void**)&f = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, sym.c_str());
```

`operator()` can use perfect forwarding:

```
Ret
operator()(Args... args)
{
    f(std::forward<Args>(args));
}
```

The wrapping will cost two moves or one copy + one move per argument passed by value and one forward for reference types. It is transparent to the client; he or she won't need to use `std::move` unless the original function would already have him required to. Notice that the first copy or move of a by-value argument must be paid no matter what; the real *opportunity* cost of the wrapper is the (potential) move that comes after that, to pass the argument to the real function.

By comparison using `Args const&...` breaks if the wrapped function is `void foo(T&&);`, due to reference collapsing rules the signature will be `void operator()(T&);`

Perhaps the macro should take the name of the variable as an argument; but that may not be necessary depending on your planned usage.

Minor pet peeve: meaningful names. I would have called the constructor parameter `symbol`. The time it takes to type three more characters each time is simply negligible compared to the time it takes to write and maintain code. `function_type` instead of `real_func` possibly, too.

Comment: +1, thanks there's quite a few interesting things for me to think about in your answer.

Comment: (also the call to `glXSwapBuffers` in the example is correct, in that it isn't recursive. The name of the variable is derived from the macro parameter x)

Comment: One of the things I was trying to work out was if I could make the constructor deduce the name of the symbol (by looking at `__FUNC__` and friends) rather than having to pass it in, but I think the `MAKE_WRAPPER` macro makes mostly that redundant.

Comment: @awoodland Looks like I forgot that `x` was the macro parameter by the time I got to reading the variable name, heh. `__func__` does get you the name of the function but as a string. So yeah, since you need the function for `decltype` that won't help.